backgroundWorker.RunworkerAsync not reaching DoWork method
I have a form that I added a backgroundWorker to, but RunworkerAsync is not reaching the DoWork method for some reason.
            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new       ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
            else {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

If I set a breakpoint inside of the DoWork method the breakpoint is never hit. I can't for the lift of me figure out why not
Here is the DoWork method:
            private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true) {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
...some code....
}

Expect the DoWork method to fire

If you put a breakpoint on backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); does it get hit?

BackgroundWorker is obsolete, not broken. It was replaced in 2021 by async/await and Progress.  Before that it was used for 10 years in almost all WinForms and WPF applications as a form component that performed work in the background. If there were any problems, hundreds of thousands of developers would notice.

The question's code is weird too, and makes me suspect it's not the real code. Why check whether backgroundWorker1 when it was just created? If some missing part of the code started it, the IsBusy check guarantees it won't start again.

I know what the "docs" say, but all I've ever needed was: this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork. (I didn't have to "new" anything "over" the existing "handler"). Same goes for the rest of the BGW events. The handler just has to match the "specification"; it doesn't need to "create" one (or whatever it thinks it's doing).

@mjwills - yes that breakpoint gets hit, but not the one in the _DoWork method

I've removed the 'new' line but the result is the same.

If I set a breakpoint inside of the DoWork method the breakpoint is never hit. So you put breakpoints on every line in DoWork and none of them were hit?

Turns out this had nothing to do with backgroundWorker. I had referenced the ArpLookup dll in my solution but ArpLookup.dll was not present in my solution's debug folder. Not sure why this would not allow the debugger to hit the breakpoint though. Sorry for the noise
